# regex match exclude bracket's string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have following string and want to match string which are not in bracket"()".

i have tried it with following but it give match with bracket and i want to its inverse.

```js
var str = '45.6 fl oz (456 g)';
console.log(str.match(/[\(]+[^\)]*\)/g));
```

Can any one help me? I want to following output:-

```
45.6 fl oz
(456 g)
```

Comment: Inside a [character set (`[...]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets) the parentheses do not have any special meaning and there is no need to escape them. `[\(]` is the same thing as `[(]` which is the same thing as `\(` (a parenthesis outside a character set needs escaping).

Comment: It seems you need further assistance with this string parsing. Please drop a comment rather than asking another question. Look, `4.5 fl oz` can be split into numbers/non-numbers the same way as I suggest in my answer: `str.split(/\s*(\d*\.?\d+)\s*/).filter(Boolean)`. But if you need `fl` there as well, probably you need to specify all the options inside a non-capturing group like `str.split(/\s*(\d*\.?\d+\s*(?:fl oz|[kmd]?g|l))\s*/).filter(Boolean)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split with `/\s*(\([^()]*\))/`:

```js
var str = '45.6 fl oz (456 g)';
console.log(str.split(/\s*(\([^()]*\))/).filter(Boolean));
//Or, split with whitespaces before a (:
console.log(str.split(/\s*(?=\()/));
```

The pattern matches

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `(\([^()]*\))` - Capturing group #1 (its value will be part of the resulting array):

  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `[^()]*` - any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a `)`.

To exclude `(` and `)` in the result, adjust the capturing group boundaries: `/\s*\(([^()]*)\)/`.

The `.filter(Boolean)` will remove redundant leading/trailing empty array items that appear when the match is found at the start/end of the string.

The second variant, `/\s*(?=\()/`, just matches 0+ whitespace chars that are immediatley followed with a `(` char (thanks to the `(?=\()` lookahead).

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture two groups essentially; one, which targets the text not in `()` and another, which targets the text in `()`:

```js
var str = '45.6 fl oz (456 g)';
console.log(str.match(/([^()])+|(\(.*\))/g).map(item => item.trim()));
```

Comment: I have try it for  '45.6 fl oz (456 g) (2.6 cup)' and it gives following output [
  "45.6 fl oz",
  "(456 g) (2.6 cup)"
]